# Why is the MSDB database TRUSTWORTHY?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, security

The `TRUSTWORTHY` setting can be rather dangerous if you aren't careful and except for specific circumstances the recommendation is to keep it turned off.  However by default the `MSDB` database has `TRUSTWORHTY` set `ON` by default.  I'm curious why?

I've read this entry in [BOL](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2183687)

> Note By default, the TRUSTWORTHY setting is set to ON for the MSDB database. Altering this setting from its default value can result in unexpected behavior by SQL Server components that use the MSDB database.

But I'm curious about specifics.  Why specifically does `MSDB` need `TRUSTWORTHY` turned on? What functions use it?

Comment: Just a quick thought without research for WHY would be so the SQL Agent service can interact with all DBs on an instance, to use DB mail for notifications, other external resources; paths, AD objects, etc. within SQL Agent jobs.

Comment: @JUICED_IT also SQL Agent job history, log shipping monitor history, SSIS packages, Database Engine Tuning Advisor data, and Service Broker queue data, and backup information. That's a lot of things that you want standard behavior from.  http://sqlperformance.com/2015/07/sql-maintenance/msdb

Comment: I suspect it is required for anything that uses cross-database calls. You should turn `TRUSTWORTHY` to OFF for `msdb` to see what stops working and you will have at least part of the answer :). I figured BACKUP would have issues but I just tried and it succeeded.

Answer (score 3):

There are dozens of objects in `msdb` that reference the `master` database.

If msdb were not marked as `TRUSTWORTHY`, then users would need permission to both the `msdb` object they are interacting with, plus the `master` object that is being referenced.

For example, msdb users who get permissions via the SQLAgentUserRole database role are granted execute on `msdb.dbo.sp_enum_sqlagent_subsystems`. The call stack for that procedure eventually hits `master`:

```
* msdb.dbo.sp_enum_sqlagent_subsystems
    * msdb.dbo.sp_enum_sqlagent_subsystems_internal
        * master.dbo.xp_instance_regread
```

If `msdb` is not marked as `TRUSTWORTHY`, then users who are part of the SQLAgentUserRole database role would ALSO need execute permission on `master.dbo.xp_instance_regread`.

Technically speaking, it is probably possible to remove the `TRUSTWORTHY` setting in `msdb` and instead grant specific permissions in `master`. However, those required permissions are neither documented nor supported.

Comment: You are probably right but if so then it is equally important that the owner of MSDB have those permissions.

Comment: @KennethFisher Probably?  I don't usually mess with the database owner for msdb, so I'm not sure. I've always just left it as sa. I legitimately hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Ahh but if I have the right permissions in MSDB I can use that sa access in combination with TRUSTWORTHY to take over your server :)

Comment: True. But this is why access to system DBs should be carefully restricted. If you're not a DBA, you don't need to get into a system database.

Comment: Could the same argument be made for SSISDB? That it must be trusworthy and it's a system database with limited access?